# Is there a way to set the maximum total cache size?

Tags: settings, insufficient-memory, cache, developer-options

The cache on my device (Samsung Galaxy S5, unrooted!) grows very quickly. Is there a way to just set the maximum allowed system-wide cache size?

My device always restarts (and takes a while restarting too!) whenever I manually clear the whole cache.

Edit: I have an external 128GB SD card too but S5 only treats it as a simple mount, not as an automatic extension of regular device storage (16GB capacity!)

Comment: I use Cache Cleaner, an open source software... You need to enable clean on open, and close after clean ... Then just tap to clean cache.... https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.frozendevs.cache.cleaner/  might be an alternative..

Comment: Sounds like you need more storage. You shouldn't need to clean the cache except for maybe a rom update or clean install.